# Java properties file in jar not found when running jar

Tags: java, maven, properties, maven-assembly-plugin

When I run `main()` from IntelliJ I got as, expected `peter,johnson` as result in standard out. But when I run `mvn clean package` and try to execute `java -jar target/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar` I get following error message. Why and how can I make sure that .properties file is read?

```
java -jar target/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException:      file:/Users/ismar.slomic/src/ADOP/example/target/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-  jar-with-dependencies.jar!/my-example.properties (No such file or   directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at com.example.MyPropertiesClass.getFullName(MyPropertiesClass.java:18)
at com.example.MyMainClass.main(MyMainClass.java:9)
```

**MyMainClass**

```
package com.example;

import java.io.IOException;

public class MyMainClass {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
       MyPropertiesClass mpc = new MyPropertiesClass();
       System.out.println(mpc.getFullName());
   }
}
```

**MyPropertiesClass**

```
package com.example;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class MyPropertiesClass {

  public String getFullName() throws IOException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
    String filePath = cl.getResource("my-example.properties").getFile();

    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filePath));
    properties.load(bis);

    String name = properties.getProperty("name");
    String lastname = properties.getProperty("lastname");
    return name + "," + lastname;
  }
}
```

**my-example.properties**

```
name=peter
lastname=johnson
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>example</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>${project.artifactId}</name>
<description>My Example</description>

<properties>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.example.MyMainClass</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your property file is inside your jar, then you'd better to use `getResourceAsStream` instead of `getResource` and `getFile`.

Something like:

```
  ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
  try (InputStream stream = cl.getResourceAsStream("my-example.properties")) {
     properties.load(bis);
  }
```

The method `getResource(String)`returns an URL that points to a file inside a jar. In your case, something like: `file:/Users/ismar.slomic/src/ADOP/example/target/example-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar!/my-example.properties`. When you call `getFile` on that URL, it returns the file (i.e. the jar) which and not the pointer to the properties file inside.

What could also work is to open a connection on the URL and use the returned `JarURLConnection`. But it is easier with `getResourceAsStream`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked. But could you please explain why `getResourceAsStream` worked and `getResource` didn´t? They are pointing to exactly same file path, the only difference is how you read the file, right?

Comment: Even with getResourceAsStream  I am getting same issue